# Report server - resourcing labels via dll

Tags: server, localization, label, report

I used [this project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33355/Localization-of-SSRS-Reports) to help me resource report labels.

After build, it generates default resource DLL and additional 3 folders with corresponding language DLL inside. Copied dlls to *private assemblies*, a report server *bin* folder, changed *config* files for VS and Report server, put all DLLs to GAC.

Report preview in Visual Studio 2017 enterprise works perfect, it translates in all languages.

On local report server 2012, report translates only to default language. It seems like it cant see other three dll-s.